# First image not showing in slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
            <style> 
                .hidden {
                    display: none;
                }           
                .imgSize {
                      height: 40px;
                      width: 70px;
                }               
                .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > div,
                .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
                      width: 100%;
                      margin: auto;
                }

                .modal1 {
                    display: none; 
                    position: fixed;
                    z-index: 1;
                    padding-top: 100px; 
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    overflow: auto; 
                    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
                }

                .modal-content1 {
                    margin: auto;
                    display: block;
                    width: 80%;
                    max-width: 614px;
                    max-height: 400px;

                }

                .modal-content1, #caption {    
                    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
                    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
                    animation-name: zoom;
                    animation-duration: 0.6s;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
                    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
                    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
                }

                @keyframes zoom {
                    from {transform:scale(0)} 
                    to {transform:scale(1)}
                }

                .close-popup {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 60px;
                    right: 35px;
                    color: #f1f1f1;
                    font-size: 40px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    transition: 0.3s;
                }

                .download-file {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 66px;
                    right: 70px;
                    color: #f1f1f1;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    transition: 0.3s;
                }

                .close:hover,
                .close:focus {
                    color: #bbb;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
                    .modal-content {
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                }
                </style>


                <script>                         

                $( document ).ready(function() {

                    $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_instruction").attr("disabled", true);                 
                    var docsCount = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_docsCount').val();
                    $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile1_div').remove();             

                    if($("#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResultStatus").val() == "Close" ){
                        $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResult").attr("disabled", true);                              
                    }else{
                        $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_submitButton_div").removeClass("hidden");                             
                        adduploadDiv(1);
                    }

                    $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_").on('click',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var index = $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_docsCount").val();
                        var nextIndex = parseInt(index)+1;
                        if(nextIndex < 6){ modifyOtheruploadDiv(nextIndex); }                       
                        $("#EditpatientResultsDetails__div").hide(); 
                        $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_submitButton_div").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResult").attr("disabled", false);
                        $("#deleteDoc1").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#deleteDoc2").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#deleteDoc3").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#deleteDoc4").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#deleteDoc5").removeClass("hidden");
                    });

                    $("[id^=deleteDoc]").on("click", function(e) {
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");
                        var idLength = id.length; 
                        var docsCount = $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_docsCount").val();
                        $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_deleteCheck").val("true");
                        $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_docsCount").val(parseInt(docsCount)-1);
                        var index = $(this).attr("id").charAt(idLength - 1);
                        var updatedDocumentCount = $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_docsCount").val();
                        var documentCnt = $("#EditpatientResultsDetails_documentCnt").val();
                        if(updatedDocumentCount == 0){
                            if(documentCnt == 5){
                                adduploadDiv(1);
                                $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_deleteCheck").val('false');
                            }else if(documentCnt == 1){
                                $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_deleteCheck").val('false');
                            }
                        }
                        var detail = new Object();
                        detail.testResultDocId = $(this).data("value");
                        $.ajax({
                                url : "ViewPatientTestResults/deleteTestResultDocs",
                                cache : false,
                                type : 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json', 
                                data: JSON.stringify(detail),
                                async: false,
                                success : function() { 
                                    $("#attachment"+index+"_display").hide();
                                }
                        });                     
                    });

                    $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
                            var doc1 = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile1').val();
                            var doc2 = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile2').val();
                            var doc3 = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile3').val();
                            var doc4 = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile4').val();
                            var doc5 = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile5').val();
                            var testResults =  $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResult').val();
                            var deleteCheck = $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_deleteCheck").val();
                            if (typeof doc1 == 'undefined'){ doc1 = ""; }
                            if (typeof doc2 == 'undefined'){ doc2 = ""; }
                            if (typeof doc3 == 'undefined'){ doc3 = ""; }
                            if (typeof doc4 == 'undefined'){ doc4 = ""; }
                            if (typeof doc5 == 'undefined'){ doc5 = ""; }
                            if(doc1 != '' || doc2 != '' || doc3 != '' || doc4 != '' || doc5 != '' || testResults != '' || deleteCheck == "true"){                                               
                            }else{
                                e.preventDefault(); 
                                alert("Either Results or Attachment is mandatory"); 
                            }
                    });                         

                    $('.close').on('click',function(){
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    });

                    for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
                        var fileExtension = $("#attachment"+i+"_display").data("value");
                        if(fileExtension == 'pdf'){
                            var currPage = 1; 
                            var numPages = 0;
                            var thePDF = null;                              
                            var fileData = $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_docUrl"+i).val();
                            showPDF(atob(fileData),i,currPage,numPages,thePDF);
                        }
                    }

                    function showPDF(pdf_url,index,currPage,numPages,thePDF){
                        PDFJS.getDocument({ data: pdf_url }).then(function(pdf) {                   
                                thePDF = pdf;                           
                                numPages = pdf.numPages;                            
                                pdf.getPage( 1 ).then( handlePages );
                        });

                        function handlePages(page)
                        {                             
                                var viewport = page.getViewport( 1 );
                                var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
                                canvas.style.display = "block";
                                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                                page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
                                document.getElementById("pdfDoc"+index).appendChild( canvas );
                                currPage++;
                                if ( thePDF !== null && currPage <= numPages )
                                {
                                    thePDF.getPage( currPage ).then( handlePages );
                                }
                        }
                    }

                    $("[id^=viewDocs]").on("click", function () {
                            var docId = $(this).attr("id");
                            var docIndex = docId.substr(docId.length - 1);
                            var activeItemId = $(this).data("value");                                           
                            $("div>div.item").removeClass("active");
                            $("#"+activeItemId).addClass("active"); 
                            var appName = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_appName').val();
                            var paramValue = $(this).data("id");
                            $("#myModal").removeClass("hidden");
                            $('#downloadDocId').attr('href',appName+'/apps/PatientDetailsDoctor/ViewPatientTestResults/downloadUploadDocs?testResultsDocsId='+paramValue);
                            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");                                                                             
                            modal.style.display = "block";                          

                    });                                 

                    $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
                      var itemId = ev.relatedTarget.id;
                      var paramValue =  $('#'+itemId).data('value');
                      var appName = $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_appName').val();
                      $('#downloadDocId').attr('href',appName+'/apps/PatientDetailsDoctor/ViewPatientTestResults/downloadUploadDocs?testResultsDocsId='+paramValue);
                    })                                              

            });


                    function addOtheruploadDiv(index){
                            var prevIndex = parseInt(index)-1;
                            var nextIndex = parseInt(index)+1;
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").hide();
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").hide();
                            var rowStr='';
                            rowStr = rowStr +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-5 " style="display: block;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'" class=" col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 fontBold  control-label">Upload </label>'
                            +'<div class=" col-sm-6 "><input type="file" size="30" value="" name="resultUploadFile'+index+'" onchange="validateFile(this);" class="validate[required] form-control" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'">'
                            +'</div></div></div>';

                            if(parseInt(index) < 5){
                            rowStr +=   '<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-1 " style="display: block; width: 30px; margin-top: 7px;">'
                                        +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" class="   "> </label><div class=" col-sm-5 ">'
                                        +'<center><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" null="" class="" onclick="addOtheruploadDiv('+nextIndex+')" "="" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" href="#" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'
                                        +'</a></center></div></div></div>';
                            }


                            rowStr +=   '<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-1 " style="display: block; width: 30px; margin-top: 7px;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs'+index+'" class="   "> </label><div class=" col-sm-5 ">'
                            +'<center><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" null="" class="" onclick="removeUploadDiv('+index+')" "="" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs'+index+'" href="#" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>'
                            +'</a></center></div></div></div>'

                            +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'_div" class="col-md-12 " style="display: block;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'" class=" col-sm-5 control-label  "> </label><div class=" col-sm-7 ">'
                            +'</div></div></div>';                              


                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+prevIndex+'_div').after(rowStr);



                        }

                        function modifyOtheruploadDiv(index){
                            var prevIndex = parseInt(index)-1;
                            var nextIndex = parseInt(index)+1;
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").hide();
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").hide();
                            var rowStr='';
                            rowStr = rowStr +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-5 " style="display: block;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'" class=" col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 fontBold  control-label">Upload </label>'
                            +'<div class=" col-sm-6 "><input type="file" size="30" value="" name="resultUploadFile'+index+'" onchange="validateFile(this);" class="validate[required] form-control" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'">'
                            +'</div></div></div>';

                            if(parseInt(index) < 5){
                            rowStr  += '<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-1 " style="display: block; width: 30px; margin-top: 7px;">'
                                    +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" class="   "> </label><div class=" col-sm-5 ">'
                                    +'<center><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" null="" class="" onclick="addOtheruploadDiv('+nextIndex+')" "="" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" href="#" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'
                                    +'</a></center></div></div></div>';
                            }

                            rowStr  += '<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'_div" class="col-md-12 " style="display: block;">'
                                    +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'" class=" col-sm-5 control-label  "> </label><div class=" col-sm-7 ">'
                                    +'</div></div></div>';                              

                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResult_div').after(rowStr);       


                        }


                        function adduploadDiv(index){
                            var nextIndex = parseInt(index)+1;
                            var rowStr='';
                            rowStr = rowStr +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-5 " style="display: block;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'" class=" col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 fontBold  control-label">Upload </label>'
                            +'<div class=" col-sm-6 "><input type="file" size="30" value="" name="resultUploadFile'+index+'" onchange="validateFile(this);" class="validate[required] form-control" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'">'
                            +'</div></div></div>'                               

                            +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'_div" class="col-sm-1 " style="display: block; width: 30px; margin-top: 7px;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" class="   "> </label><div class=" col-sm-5 ">'
                            +'<center><a title="" data-toggle="tooltip" null="" class="" onclick="addOtheruploadDiv('+nextIndex+')" "="" id="SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'" href="#" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'
                            +'</a></center></div></div></div>'

                            +'<div id="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'_div" class="col-md-12 " style="display: block;">'
                            +'<div class="form-group"><label for="SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'" class=" col-sm-5 control-label  "> </label><div class=" col-sm-7 ">'
                            +'</div></div></div>';  

                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_testResult_div').after(rowStr);                                   

                        }


                        function removeUploadDiv(index){                                
                            var prevIndex = parseInt(index)-1;
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").show();
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs"+prevIndex+"_div").show();
                            $("#SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField"+prevIndex+"_div").show(); 

                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_resultUploadFile'+index+'_div').remove();
                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_addDocs'+index+'_div').remove();
                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_removeDocs'+index+'_div').remove();
                            $('#SavepatientResultsDetails_emptyField'+index+'_div').remove();
                        }

                        function validateFile(param){
                                var Msg =$('[id^=SavepatientResultsDetails_fileError]').val();
                                if(param.files[0].size/1024 > 500){
                                    alert('Upload file size should be lesser than 500KB');
                                    $(param).val('');                               
                                }else{                               
                                     var fileUpload = $(param)[0];                              
                                     var regexPNG = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:;()*\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>~`])+(.png)$");
                                     var regexJPG = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:;()*\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>~`])+(.jpg)$");
                                     var regexPDF = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:;()*\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>~`])+(.pdf)$");
                                     if (regexPNG.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) || regexJPG.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) || regexPDF.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) )
                                     {
                                        return true;
                                     } else {
                                         alert(Msg);
                                         $(param).val('');
                                         $(param).focus();        
                                        return false;
                                     }
                                }

                        }
```

First image of the slide is not displaying, only in chrome browser. When the image start to move It works fine, It shown the hidden image. I have try adding jquery "visibility: visible !important", but it doesn't solved.     It seems to work fine on both Safari and Internet Explorer.This is my working part of the code.

Comment: yep. you right. i cant see your image too

Comment: you genius buddy...